# installation - Can't install Shotwell on Ubuntu 19.04, dconf-tools is missing

Tags: apt, dependencies, 19.04, dconf, shotwell

When I use `sudo apt-get install shotwell`, I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:

    shotwell : Depends: dconf-tools but it is not installable

    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install `dconf-tools` it says (just like it said above):

```
Package dconf-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dconf-tools' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to install Shotwell from the Software Center but had the error:

```
Unable to install Shotwell:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

Output of `apt-cache policy shotwell` as requested by @guiverc:

```
shotwell:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.30.4-0~jensge0~disco2
  Version table:
     0.30.4-0~jensge0~disco2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yg-jensge/shotwell/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     0.30.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
```

<s>I also tried to install it from Flatpak, but I had problems on it where it didn't see my folders in the home directory (on which I didn't find a similar question around the web), so I wanted to try the alternative way to install it. I installed Shotwell on my other PC from the repos by `sudo apt-get install shotwell` and had no problems.</s>

I'm using Xubuntu 19.04 on both of my computers.

Comment: Have you done an `apt-get update` followed by an `apt-get upgrade` recently?  Try starting off with that.

After that you need to figure out what packages you have put on hold.  (You have held broken packages)  Can you give us the output of `dpkg -l | grep ^h`

Comment: "The following packages have unmet dependencies" should be followed by a list of packages which are key to fixing your issues. They'll show if you have problems with your sources, but without that detail we cannot provide clues. Check http://packages.ubuntu.com yourself if you don't want us to see your package problems & help.

Comment: @guiverc I don't mind listing them but that is the whole message given in the Software Center when I try to install it.

Comment: @jawtheshark both `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` didn't help. `dpkg -l | grep ^h` didn't give any output.

Comment: Can you please add `apt-cache policy shotwell` to your question. Your messages imply `dconf-tools` is a requirement, however https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/shotwell shows it isn't for 19.04 as I read it.

Comment: Do you mean add as a tag? (I'm sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: `apt-cache` is an apt (package) command, ie. execute it and add the command & output to your question is what I request (ie. edit your question & add detail there, format it with {} \)

Comment: I agree with guiverc that there should be a list unmet dependencies and/or broken packages.  I'm surprised you have no held packages, because that's how it looked.

Try to fix your broken packages: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/

Comment: @guiverc oh ok, done.

Comment: You're not getting your packages from official sources, but 3rd parties. `dconf-tools` is **not** a requirement for the official package, but must be for the 3rd party personal-package-archive....  You may have to check the requirements for the PPA packages with it's author, as Ubuntu web tools don't include 3rd party sources (such as personal-package-archives; security is all on you for them)  *Another user may have knowledge with that PPA; I stick to official sources if possible as they've been audited/reviewed/..*

Comment: @guiverc yes I think you are right because after I deleted the repository I get the Shotwell packages from and then tried `sudo apt-get install shotwell`, it started installing. By doing this I am getting the official packages, right?

Comment: I can't know for sure,  I'd want to view your sources (/etc/apt/sources.list & anything in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/) so you'll have to check what's there yourself (or you can `sudo apt update` & scan it's output for clues!).  If you want to see a source for a package, use the command I asked you to run before, ie. `apt-cache policy <package>` and it'll show you all sources you have listed that provide the package and their versions (the highest will install).  Official sources aren't a problem when release-upgrade time comes, (ie. when you jump to 19.10); where as PPA's can be a problem then!

Comment: Understood, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I removed the unofficial repository from where Shotwell was tried to be installed. After removing it and trying to install it with `sudo apt-get install shotwell`, I didn't encounter the same problem.